# Cartesian product and Division in Relational Algebra

Tags: relational-theory

Let be the following database sketch:

> Cineroom(Name, Hour, Name)
>
> Film(Name, Director, Actor)
>
> Saw(Spectator, Name)
>
> Produce(Producer, Name)
>
> Likes(Amateur, Name)

How to express, in relational algebra the difference between:

- *which actors played in a film they produced?*
- *which actor produced a film?*

To my mind it was the difference between Cartesian product and outer join:

Π<sub>Actor</sub>(σ<sub>Producer=Actor</sub>(Film ⋈ Produce))

Π<sub>Actor</sub>(σ<sub>Producer=Actor</sub>(Film*Produce))

Would it allow to join only the films the actor played and produced in the first case?